# How many grams of anthracite coal is needed to convert to steam?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

So I have searched the internet but it would not give me the answer that will truly satisfy the question.  I hope someone could answer this

Answer (score 2):

The energy released when you burn something is called the *enthalpy of combustion*, so you can find the data you need by Googling for *anthracite enthalpy combustion* or something like that. When I did this I found some data on the [Engineering Toolbox](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/fuels-higher-calorific-values-d_169.html) that gives the enthalpy of combustion as around 33MJ/kg.

The next step is to work out how much water 33MJ will boil. If $C$ is the specific heat of water and $L$ is the latent heat of water (both per kg) then the energy required to boil a mass $m$ of water is:

$$ E = m \left(C(100 - T_0) + L\right) $$

where $T_0$ is the initial temperature of the water. Google for values for $C$ and $L$, set $E$ equal to the 33MJ from burning 1kg of anthracite, and you can solve for the mass of water boiled, $m$.

Comment: Thanks but what do you mean by the latent heat?  Is it supposed to be of the coal's or the water?

Comment: @AlmondBaby: $L$ is the latent heat of the water i.e. it is the heat required to convert 1kg of water at 100°C to 1kg of steam at 100°C.